# Add a MenuItem to Other applications Option/Action menu (Android)

Tags: android

Is it possible to add a new Menu Item to other application's Option/Action menu?

For example:
In phone's contacts menu, I want to add a new menu item "Share on Orkut (example)".

Is it possible in Android?

Thanks
Souvik

Comment: Unless you get the source and recompile yourself, this is not possible.

Comment: It depends fx look here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html   ... It is posible to add 'share with whatever' from contact app since it just creating intentChooser and if your app has proper intent filters it can be listed there (intencohooser appears when you do longclick on contact and select share card with) ...

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible to modify other applications' behavior in code

Comment: Well you cant modify other application but still there is a possibility  so this is not good answer for this question ... See my comments

Comment: i believe he is talking about **Menu** button options defined under *R.menu*

Comment: Hi Selvin, that blog was really helpful. But how do I know the intent filters I can use to accomplish this?